# What's causing Python Segmentation error?

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, psycopg2

My Python process closes with a Segmentation Fault which occurs anywhere between half an hour to 6-7 hours after starting it.

I'm not able to figure our which part of the code is causing the Segmentation Fault. I tried to make some changes in code, but those didn't help, so I added `faulthandler` to explicitly dump the stacktrace. There are no errors in the code itself as the error logs have nothing related to any errors or exceptions in the code.

```
Fatal Python error: Aborted

Thread 0x00007f67b515e700 (most recent call first):
  File "main_v2.py", line 64 in exec_query
  File "main_v2.py", line 101 in record_event
  File "main_v2.py", line 212 in v1_feed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask_cors/decorator.py", line 128 in wrapped_function
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799 in dispatch_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813 in full_dispatch_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292 in wsgi_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 258 in execute
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270 in run_wsgi
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 328 in handle_one_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 422 in handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 293 in handle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681 in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354 in finish_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 625 in process_request_thread
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 882 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00007f67affff700 (most recent call first):
  File "main_v2.py", line 64 in exec_query
  File "main_v2.py", line 101 in record_event
  File "main_v2.py", line 212 in v1_feed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask_cors/decorator.py", line 128 in wrapped_function
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799 in dispatch_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813 in full_dispatch_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292 in wsgi_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 258 in execute
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270 in run_wsgi
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 328 in handle_one_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 422 in handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 293 in handle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681 in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354 in finish_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 625 in process_request_thread
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 882 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f67bca3e700 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 376 in select
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 232 in serve_forever
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 612 in serve_forever
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 777 in inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 814 in run_simple
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 943 in run
  File "main_v2.py", line 224 in run_server
  File "main_v2.py", line 241 in main
  File "main_v2.py", line 246 in <module>
```

I am unable to understand why the stacktrace mentions different `threads` while I'm not using any `threads` in my code.

- The `File "main_v2.py", line 64 in exec_query` is a `cur.execute()`
  command from `psycopg2`
- `"main_v2.py", line 101 in record_event` is
  a call to the exec_query function above
- `"main_v2.py", line 212 in
  v1_feed` is a call to the `record_event` function above.

None of these statements seem to have an error. The following are the external modules I'm using:

- coloredlogs
- Flask
- pytz
- requests
- Flask_Cors
- psycopg2_binary
- psycopg2

Please,I'd be thankful for any help on figuring out what might be causing the issue.

**UPDATE** : I was able to resolve the issue by using `threaded=False` in Flask app.run(). Although I'm not sure *why* it works. So if someone might be able to point out what was causing it, that'll be of great help.

Comment: Based on the path names, I get the impression that you are using different, interfering Python/library versions. Please try to create a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and run your code from there. My guess is that this should solve your problem. Please let us know if it does.

Comment: @agtoever Thanks for the response, I tried running it in a virtualenv by installing all the dependencies again, but unfortunately that didn't help :(

Comment: @agtoever Can you please take a look at the updated question? That might give you some additional info as to what was causing the issue.